# Nested data structure of User-Defined Type in Fortran

Tags: pointers, memory-leaks, fortran, user-defined-types, allocatable-array

I'm looking for a way to build a tree structure using a User-Defined Type in Fortran 2008. While I can get some basic code working, I'm encountering memory leaks I am unable to pinpoint.

The tree structure does not have to be overly generic since it's being used as a one-time insert and multiple-read kind of storage, which is why I decided to use allocatables. Since Fortran does not allow to use a type for an allocatable as one of its own members, I am using an intermediate structure referenced by a pointer to store that allocatable. So, the following is what I would like to use, but is not allowed:

```
type :: invalid_section
  type(invalid_section), dimension(:), allocatable :: subsections
end type
```

In the following example I'm using a lazy allocation (only allocate it when there are child nodes to add/present) of that pointer to the type holding the allocatable.

```
module sectiontest

   type :: section
      type(subsections), pointer :: subsections_ => null()

      contains
         procedure, pass(self) :: section_assign
         generic :: assignment(=) => section_assign

         final :: section_cleanup, section_cleanup_arr
   end type

   type :: subsections
      type(section), dimension(:), allocatable :: arr
   end type

   interface section
      module procedure constructor
   end interface

contains

   type(section) function constructor(subsections)
      type(section), optional, intent(in) :: subsections(:)
      integer :: idx

      print *, "constructor"

      if (present(subsections)) then
         print *, "allocating subsection"
         allocate(constructor%subsections_)
         allocate(constructor%subsections_%arr(size(subsections)))
         do idx=1,size(subsections)
            ! make sure we recursively copy everything
            constructor%subsections_%arr(idx) = subsections(idx)
         enddo
      endif
   end function

   recursive subroutine section_assign(self, rhs)
      class(section), intent(inout) :: self
      type(section), intent(in) :: rhs
      integer :: idx

      print *, "assign"
      if (associated(self%subsections_)) then
         deallocate(self%subsections_)
      endif

      if (associated(rhs%subsections_)) then
         print *, "allocation subsection"
         allocate(self%subsections_)
         allocate(self%subsections_%arr(size(rhs%subsections_%arr)))

         do idx=1,size(rhs%subsections_%arr)
            self%subsections_%arr(idx) = rhs%subsections_%arr(idx)
         enddo
      endif
   end subroutine

   recursive subroutine section_cleanup(sec)
      type(section), intent(inout) :: sec

      print *, "section_cleanup"
      if (associated(sec%subsections_)) then
         print *, "  deallocated a subsection"
         deallocate(sec%subsections_)
      endif
   end subroutine

   recursive subroutine section_cleanup_arr(arr)
      type(section), dimension(:), intent(inout) :: arr
      integer :: idx

      print *, "deallocating array of sections of size:", size(arr)

      do idx=1,size(arr)
         print *, "deallocating subsection array index", idx
         if (associated(arr(idx)%subsections_)) then
            print *, "  deallocated a subsection"
            deallocate(arr(idx)%subsections_)
         endif
      end do
   end subroutine

   subroutine demo()
      type(section) :: root

      root = section(subsections=[ &
         section(subsections=[section(), section(), section()]), &
         section() &
         ])
   end subroutine
end module sectiontest
```

```
program main
   use sectiontest
   implicit none

   call demo()
end program
```

From `gfortran` (7 and 9), `flang` and `nagfor` I get direct memory leaks originating from `allocate(constructor%subsections_)` in the `constructor`.

Here from `gfortran-7` and built with `-fsanitize=address`:

```
==26536==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Direct leak of 48 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7f965539c510 in malloc (/usr/lib64/libasan.so.4+0xdc510)
    #1 0x407e35 in __sectiontest_MOD_constructor /users/tiziano/work/tests/fortran/cp2k_input_parser/recursive_mwe.f90:31
    #2 0x40432a in __sectiontest_MOD_demo /users/tiziano/work/tests/fortran/cp2k_input_parser/recursive_mwe.f90:92
    #3 0x4090d9 in MAIN__ /users/tiziano/work/tests/fortran/cp2k_input_parser/recursive_mwe_prog.f90:5
    #4 0x409119 in main /users/tiziano/work/tests/fortran/cp2k_input_parser/recursive_mwe_prog.f90:2
    #5 0x7f96543c2f89 in __libc_start_main (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x20f89)
```

I'm looking for either an alternative implementation (but preferably a similar elegant initialization) or an explanation and possible solution for the memory leak.

Comment: "since Fortran does not allow cyclic allocatable references in UDTs" - could you clarify what you mean?  Are you referring to a type containing an allocatable component of the same type, or objects circularly referencing each other?

Comment: @IanH I've updated the first part of the question to address this, the first one : "a type containing an allocatable component of the same type"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fortran 2008 supports a type containing an allocatable component of the type being defined.  This simplifies the code to:

```
module sectiontest
   type :: section
      type(section), allocatable :: subsections(:)
   end type
contains
   subroutine demo()
      type(section) :: root

      root = section( subsections=[ &
         section(subsections=[section(), section(), section()]), &
         section() ])
   end subroutine
end module sectiontest

program main
   use sectiontest
   implicit none

   call demo()
end program
```

Recent versions of gfortran support this language feature.

For compilers that do not sufficiently support Fortran 2008, the code in the question is a reasonable work around and will work on compilers that correctly implement Fortran 2003.

However, gfortran (up to 9.1.1 at least) does not correctly implement finalization of function results - hence the observed memory leak.

Comment: Ok, I've tried your solution before and I've tried it again now. With gfortran-9.1.0 I still get a `Fortran runtime error: Recursive call to nonrecursive procedure '__deallocate_sectiontest_Section'`. The only compilers I've found so far which are able to build and seem to generate valid code are Intel or Cray, while NAG and flang don't support it. But with the additional comment I think you answered the initial question: it's valid code, only compilers don't support it properly. Thanks!